# html - div, minimal size

Tags: html, height

how can i set minimal height for div? But it have to resize with new data.

Comment: Something that sets a minimum height... hmmm. Did you search for this answer at all first?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the CSS property [`min-height`](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_dim_min-height.asp). You'll need to be careful of not great browser support (particularly older versions of IE, shockingly enough).

Answer (score 1):

`min-height` works fine... except in IE.

The way to fix it and therefore use it everywhere is importing [ie7.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/)

Comment: Yeah, and when JS is disabled? Plus the extra overhead... even if it solves other things I don't think it's worth it. But props to Dean E. for the idea.

Comment: This is still better than having it breaking all the time. People with JS disabled are used to see broken websites anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

```
div#name
{
    height: 60px;
    height: auto !important;
    min-height: 60px;
}
```

This should work across browsers including IE

Answer (score 0):

```
div#foo {
min-height:10em;
}
```

in ie6.css or prepend with * html selector ( hack warning )

```
div#foo { height:10em; }
```

Since MSIE6 doesn't support min-height.

Comment: Or you could use conditional comments instead of a css hack.

Comment: Note that my second example was catered to IE6 only, it didn't contain star html. I just threw that in there for completion.